# How to use the console or terminal inside of a unit test method in c# visual studio 2019 to display output and receive input from user?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, input, output, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to write code that will prompt the user and ask what test files they want to test (I need to be able to test different customer files that come in and all of the files start with a customer name). Then, I want to move the files that match what the user gave to a folder, where the unit tests that I created can grab them and run tests on them. I'm having trouble getting the console to show up even when a Console.writeLine() function is called (which obviously then I can't enter anything into the console in response to what should've been displayed on the console).

I've tried using a [ClassInitialize] tag and calling the methods that prompt the user inside of this tagged method. I tried also calling those same methods at the top of my unit test method ([TestMethod]) which didn't work either. I know that the output will be under "Open additional output for this result" in the test explorer but that is not helpful for me.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void CompareModels()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter customer that you want to test: ");
        var userInput = Console.ReadLine();
        var testFiles = Directory.GetFiles("my test file directory");
        foreach(var file in testFiles)
        {
            if(file.Contain(userInput)
                File.Move(file, "my in testing directory");
        }
    }
```

I expected the console to show up on the first line of code but it doesn't and the program waits forever on the console.ReadLine() because I can't enter any input in a console that won't appear.
I would also like to add that if the user doesn't enter anything for a few seconds, then the tests will run with the files that are found in the "in testing" directory. Thus the user can change the customer being tested without manually moving files, or simply run the tests and they will do all the work for them.

Comment: Unit tests usually use theorys and theorydata for things like this. Accepting user input in a unit test is usually a bad idea.

Comment: I agree, unit tests should be 100% programmatic and not have any user interactions whatsoever.

Comment: Also agree. Your approach would make automated testing impossible.

Comment: The testing framework doesn't care that you don't care. It's not going to present a terminal or accept any input through the console.

Comment: I have doubts this will help anyone. If it were me, I'd be a little mad you're forcing me to interact with the test when I could be doing more productive things.

Comment: This is not really a unit test. More like a static analysis tool, I'd write an app to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right approach is to isolate the logic to be tested from the UI and, if possible, from the physical data source (file system, database). We can test the pure logic, if we inject it an abstraction of a file service. For testing, we can supply a test dummy. You can test whether the methods of the dummy are called the expected number of times with the right parameters. Of course, you can supply a real file service if you are willing to set up test folders and files for this.

```
public interface IFileService
{
    string[] GetFiles(string path);
    void Move(string sourceFileName, string destFileName);
}
```

Implementation of logic with injected service:

```
public class FileMover
{
    private readonly IFileService _fileService;

    public FileMover(IFileService fileService)
    {
        _fileService = fileService;
    }

    public void MoveFiles(string sourceDir, string destinationDir, string filterText)
    {
        string[] testFiles = _fileService.GetFiles(sourceDir);
        foreach (string file in testFiles) {
            if (file.Contains(filterText)) {
                _fileService.Move(file, destinationDir);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can use a mocking framework to create test dummies. They automatically create an instrumented class from an interface you can configure to do things. The dummy automatically counts method calls and registers their parameters, returns what you configured etc.

Test without console:

```
[TestMethod]
public void CompareModels()
{
    // Arrange
    IFileService fileService = Substitute.For<IFileService>();
    //TODO: setup fileService Dummy.

    var sut = new FileMover(fileService); // sut stands for Service Under Test.
    string sourceDir = @"C:\Test\Source";
    string destDir = @"C:\Test\Destination";
    string userInput = "abcd";

    // Act
    sut.MoveFiles(sourceDir, destDir, userInput);

    // Assert
    //TODO: test whether the fileService methods have been called as expected.
}
```

In the real console app:

```
var fileService = new RealFileService();
var mover = new FileMover(fileService);

Console.WriteLine("Please enter customer that you want to test: ");
string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
mover.MoveFiles("my test file directory", "my in testing directory", userInput);
```

If you do this consequently you will want to use a [Dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) container. This requires you to define all your services through an interface.

```
public interface IFileMover
{
    void MoveFiles(string sourceDir, string destinationDir, string filterText);
}

public class FileMover : IFileMover
{
    ...
}
```

Set up the DI container:

```
var diContainer = new SomeDependencyInjectionContainer();
diContainer.Register<IFileService, RealFileService>();
diContainer.Register<IFileMover, FileMover>();
```

The DI container automatically recognizes and creates the services it has to inject through the constructor. So you can then simply create a file mover with

```
var mover = diContainer.Resolve<IFileMover>();
```

A `RealFileService` will automatically be injected.